# Flink: Access operator state after execution is complete

Tags: state, apache-flink

Assuming I have a custom RichFunction with some raw state. How can I get the state (from every parallel instance of the operator) back to the main/driver code when the flink jobs ends?

```
abstract class MyRichMap extends RichMapFunction[SomeType, Unit] {

  protected var someVar: Engine = _ 

  override def open(parameters: Configuration): Unit = {
    // assume someVar inititation here
    ....
  }

  override def map(value: SomeType): Unit = {

    engine.process(value)

  }
```

```
    val env = StreamExecutionEnvironment.getExecutionEnvironment
    ...
    someSource.map (new MyRichMap())

    env.execute()
    // How to get engine or some field of it here? (e.g., engine.someCounter)
```

what's the best way to approach this?

Comment: In a true streaming job the state inside of `MyRichMap` is never "done", so what exactly do you mean by "get the state"? The state at time X? The complete state snapshot whenever it changes? Maybe a better question is why you think you need to get the state back to the main/driver code.

Comment: Fair enough. Is there anyway to get the state at anytime back to the driver code? Can I access the metrics inside the driver code and set some custom counters?

Comment: You can use custom counters, yes. But there are limits to the number of unique counters. So my question is still _why_ do you need to get state back to the main/driver code.

Comment: Well, I have a single thread implementation of the engine and now I'm trying to make it distributed with flink. I want to make some unit tests and ensure that both implementations produce the same results. For a start, checking if some counters are equal would be ok. But in the distributed version I'll have to aggregate these fields of every engine first. That is why i want to get the state back to the driver code.

Comment: Another idea would be to alter the flink operators. E.g., I could change the richmap to richfilter and emit this profiling info whenever certain conditions are met and then use a sink. But that would cause extra burden to the application. What do flink developers do in these situations?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to test `MyRichMap()`, then you'd start with unit tests - see https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/dev/stream/testing.html

If you want to test a complete workflow, a simple approach inside of a single JVM (e.g. running locally command line or Eclipse) is to create a sink that captures results to a (thread-safe) singleton, and then check the contents. That implies your sources complete (are bounded) so the workflow will terminate.